# How to capture more than 1 image in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

i want to take 4 images repeatedly and save it to my custom folder and want to display it on screen in below format.

```
_________________________________________
| Image1        |     Image2             | 
|               |                        |
|_______________|________________________|
| Image3        |    Image4              |
|               |                        |
|_______________|________________________|

MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

Using this i am able to get only one image and comes back and to take it i have to open it again.
I want to take 4 images in a single event and display it on screen.

```
btn_takeimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File imgFile = new File(file+File.separator+"Images"+File.separator+"images30.jpg");
            Uri uriSavedImage= FileProvider.getUriForFile(CameraApp.this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",imgFile);
            camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(camera, 1);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Succesfully Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error While capturing image`", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

or if it can be implemented in another method.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that. The intent data can contain only one image object if I am not wrong. You need to pick it up from the Gallery only.

Comment: if it can be implemented in any other method like custom camera or something like this.

Comment: Yea that can be done. But I am not sure how you'd redirect to a selection intent of Gallery after you have completed clicking not just 4 pictures but rather four pictures of certain requirements such as clarity.